# avoid disconnection on page refresh in socket.io

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I am currently working on a chat module.  I don't want the client to disconnect on page refresh, but on refresh it disconnects the client and makes a new connection.  Also there is data loss of client messages.

So how to avoid this disconnection and how can I retain chat messages on refresh?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to prevent a disconnection on page refresh. You could theoretically have a second window popup which handles communications, but that's way hacky. I suggest communicating with server via unique tokens. Server generates a unique token for client, each time client responds with same token after a disconnection, server handles finding the old connection and replace it with the new one